# how to disable move construct base class from derived class?

Tags: c++, subclass, copy-constructor, base-class, move-constructor

In the following code, I want to disable the move construction of base class `Vector` from derived class `VectorMap`, and call the copy constructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>

struct Vector{
    int* _ptr=nullptr;
    int _size=0;
    Vector(int n){
      _ptr = new int[n];
      _size = n;
      std::cout<< " Construct "<<this<<std::endl;
    }

    Vector(void) { std::cout <<" Construct " << this << std::endl; }

    virtual ~Vector(void) {
      if (_ptr != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Deconstruct " << this << " -> delete " << _ptr << std::endl;
        delete _ptr;
        return;
      }
      std::cout << "Deconstruct " << this << std::endl;
    }

    Vector(Vector&& v2) noexcept {
        int* p2=v2._ptr; int s2=v2._size;
        v2._ptr=_ptr;
        v2._size=_size;
        _ptr=p2; _size=s2;
        std::cout << "Move construct " << this << std::endl;
    }

    Vector(const Vector& v3){
        _ptr=new int[v3._size];
        _size=v3._size;
        memcpy(_ptr,v3._ptr,sizeof(int) * _size);
    }
};

struct VectorMap
    : public Vector {
        VectorMap(int* p,int size){
            _ptr=p;
            _size=size;
        }
        ~VectorMap(void) override {
            _ptr=nullptr; _size=0;
        }
};

int main(void) {
    Vector v1(10);
    Vector v2=VectorMap(v1._ptr,5);  // v1._ptr will be deleted twice 
    return sizeof(v2);
}
```

As you can see, if move constructor is called in the line `Vector v2=VectorMap(v1._ptr,5);`, the data pointer in `v1` will be deleted twice, one is by `v2`, and another is by `v1`. Since they share the same pointer. Is there any way to modify `VectorMap` to call copy constructor rather than move constructor in such case?

Comment: Unrelated: Re: `~Vector(void)` and `~VectorMap(void)` - Remove `void` from there. It serves no purpose and just looks bad.

Comment: Thanks for your apply, doo mean i should change the `move constructor` rather than `VectorMap`?

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is muddy ownership semantics.

`Vector` creates a resource (dynamic array), and is apparently intended to have unique ownership over it.

`VectorMap` on the other hand takes a pointer in its constructor, and gives it to its base `Vector` that takes ownership. But right before destruction, `VectorMap` rescinds the ownership by setting the base `Vector` pointer to null. So, `VectorMap` sort of pretends to own the resource until it's time for the responsibility of the ownership at which point it backs down.

This inheritance also causes other problem situations. Consider for example making a copy of `VectorMap`. Look at what the copy constructor of the base does. It allocates memory for the copy. But the desturctor of the `VectorMap` copy sets the pointer to null, so in this case the pointer is deleted zero times. It leaks memory.

As an analogy, disabling slicing would be a bandage for the wound, but what you really should do is to not stick your hand inside a running blender. If `VectorMap` is supposed to not have ownership, then it shouldn't inherit a base that takes ownership. It's unclear to me what the point of `VectorMap` class even is.

Furthermore, a class that has unique ownership of a resource such as `Vector` really should encapsulate that bare pointer with private access specifier. Sure, such classes sometimes still provide a way to copy or throw away that value (like `std::vector::data` and `std::unique_ptr::release`), but it's important that only happens through a specific function to reduce chance of accidental violation of ownership semantics.

---

Another serious bug:

```
_ptr=new int[v3._size];
// ...
delete _ptr;
```

You must not `delete` a pointer to a dynamic array. You must use `delete[]`. Using `delete` results in undefined behaviour.

---

Another bug: You forgot to include the header that declares `memcpy`. Also, I would recommend using `std::copy` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that I have ignored too many problems. But what the right design of `VectorMap` should be? I want a class that takes a pointer and a size and acts like `Vector` while it does not allocate new memory.

Comment: @Nolazuck Sounds like what you want is `std::span`.

Comment: OK,  I will try.